# Android getting new message from firebase using ChildEventListener

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

So I want to get the newest message every a message is sent to firebase, but everytime I send a new message to firebase, the log will display every message that are under "messages". What do I need to change in the code so that my log only displays the latest message that firebase has received.

[image]

```
 mDatabase.child("messages").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

                        Log.d(TAG, "new msg added: " + dataSnapshot.getKey());

                        Log.d(TAG, "msg content: " + dataSnapshot.getValue());



                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [limit the number of results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#limit_the_number_of_results).

> You can use the limitToFirst() and limitToLast() methods to set a maximum number of children to be synced for a given callback. For example, if you use limitToFirst() to set a limit of 100, you initially only receive up to 100 onChildAdded() callbacks. If you have fewer than 100 items stored in your Firebase database, an onChildAdded() callback fires for each item.
>
> As items change, you receive onChildAdded() callbacks for items that enter the query and onChildRemoved() callbacks for items that drop out of it so that the total number stays at 100.

Example:

```
mDatabase.child("messages").limitToFirst(1).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: so I added mDatabase.child("messages").limitToLast(1), and deleted all the records under "messages", when I added the first child, the log returns one result, but when I add the second child, the log would return two same results, and the number of results returned would increase with the number of child added. What's causing this to happen?

Comment: Interesting issue. Are you sure you have added only one `ChildEventListener`? You can set a number of them and each one would be called.

Comment: Okay apprently I put the `ChildEventListener` inside Send buttons's `OnClickListener`, I moved the code outside of the `OnClickListener`, now my log only returns one result for every child added. Thanks.